# A 2- cocycle $\tau$ which is not cyclic but it still satisfies the stability of $\tau(e,e,e)$ for idempotent $e$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology, cyclic-homology

I learned the following statement from page $20$ of the book Noncommutative Geometry by Alain Connes:

Let $\tau$ be a $2$-cyclic cocyle on a $C^*$ algebra. Then for every smooth curve $e(t)$ of idempotents of $A$, the quantity $\tau(e(t),e(t),e(t))$ is contsant, namely it is independent of $t$.

My question is that is there a 2-cocyle which is not cyclic but it still satisfies the above stability property?